# Camera button long press event in windows tablet

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am trying to make a torch application in windows tablet. The ultimate aim is that **"User should have immediate access to the torch"**. I managed to put the application in the settings tab of **charms bar**. But it requires 2 clicks, first on the setings bar then torch application.

- Is it possible to put the application in the charms bar itself?, so the user can launch the application with a single click.
- Or is there any way to get a trigger from external keys?. Something
  like, "long press on the volume key will launch the application", or "long press on camera button etc..".

Any Help will be highly appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no way to launch the app in the Charms bar.

You can register a event handler to HardwareButtons.CameraPressed 
`HardwareButtons.CameraPressed += HardwareButtons_CameraPressed;`.

**NOTE**

By using `HardwareButtons` you shold first add reference of Mobile Extensions if you are developing UWP apps.